# How to stop tor command line?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

How to stop tor in the most elegant way possible using only the command line?
I'm ok with starting tor using tor -f [args] but what about a tor -stop command?Does it exist?
I want to avoid systemctl because it doesn't accept args

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the answer:

```
torctl stop
```

Here's how I found it. I opened the `/usr/lib/systemd/system/tor.service` file and saw that the commands used by systemd are:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/torctl start
ExecReload=/usr/bin/torctl reload
ExecStop=/usr/bin/torctl stop
```

So you absolutely can use arguments with systemctl. You just have to put them into the `.service` config file.

Of course, this answer may vary slightly depending on your Linux distribution, but since you didn't specify which one you use, I am providing the answer for OpenSUSE which is the distro that I use.

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong with pure unix-way?

```
kill -9 `pidof tor`
```